# ASCII file parsing speed

Tags: c#, parsing, ascii

I have two type of file. One of them is ASCII file and data is stored like;

```
X Y Value 
0 0 5154,4
1 0 5545455;
. . ...
. . ...
```

other one is a binary file.

I parse first one with `StreamReader` and `ReadLine()` method and then setting values to an `double[,]` array by `Split(' ')`.

I parse second one with `BinaryReader`.

Parsing of binary file is 3-4 times faster than ASCII one.

Question 1: Reading ASCII file is slower than binary one. Is it normal?

Question 2: Do you suggest another way for parsing ASCII file?

Comment: Reading text and parsing it to convert the data to binary will be slower than reading the binary directly. 3-4 times slower isn't out of the question, especially if the file is cached (thus greatly reducing I/O time). Show us the code you're using to do your parsing.

Comment: In either case, you should read the entire stream into memory before parsing.

Comment: @DavidLively - Why that? Then he would measure something completely different; and for a large file (not unreasonable for such kind of data) it might not even be practical.

Comment: What are you comparing? Same amount of doubles or same amount of bytes? Did you compensate for caching?

Comment: Read the entire file in, only if it was a little one. ReadToEnd followed by Split(Environment.NewLine) versus Readline is a dubious trade off. Worse still if you want need a cancel / break / rewind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much reading ascii is slower, but how you do it.

It's parsing, looking for new lines, seperators, then converting bits of text to other formats. BinaryReader is basically a straight memory copy.

It's like the difference between fixed length and csv, or csv and xml The more meta data you add, the more you can get out it but the more it costs.

Reading an ascii file character by character might work out faster than readline and split, in that you could optimise it for your specific file structure. Lot of work though and very fragile making it a dubious prospect. Chucking loading to a seperate thread perhaps even parallel processing the lines, might be more rewarding, definitely be more satisfying and reusable.

Comment: at first i read and parsed ascii file char by char but that way was slower. i think because of lots of irregular "space" char count.

Comment: There's ways and means but you end up with your optimisations cancelling each other out and extremely complex code to do a simple task. If you need to do it, all it's really saying is ascii was a poor choice.

Answer (score 3):

Reading from ASCII file and binary not different, different is parsing of them,after reading ASCII file you parse string to double, this is got process time.But in binary file your read data stream is completely equals to equivalent binary double number and not need to parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Once a month we receive a 350 MB csv file with 3.5 million rows, then we used to read it one line at a time and make some indexes, it took aprox. 60 seconds every time the service was restarted.
I made a program that boiled it down to 1.7 million rows and converted it to a binary format to aprox 24 MB.
These data was read directly into memory in 7 ms and the indexes was generated when needed and the data was converted when used.
The memory consumption declined from 400 MB til 90 MB.
The point is that you should choose an appropriate format for your data if performance is an issue, also note that this solution is only possible because the data is fairly static and that the data is not retrieved more than a few million times in 24 hours.
I believe that the new service actually answers a little faster now than it used to.